# SoundBlaster Z and Kernel 4.18

Tags: sound, kernel, 18.04, soundcard, sound-blaster

I have a Creative Soundblaster Z SB1570 (yeah I know big mistake) and I read somewhere that the 4.18 kernel will have better support for this card. My question is how can I make it work earlier using this kernel before the kernel update will be released officially to all 18.04 users? I read also that there is a patch for this card. Is this needed as well?

I am sorry if my question is too broad, but basically I need the steps that I need to follow in order to make the sound card work properly.

P.S.: I tried myself to install this specific kernel and I succeeded, but I didn't get the sound card to work properly.

**EDIT:**

[**alsa-info output**](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=1e003dca607d1585e65da8285ee1c6c77d30fdc5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Install Updated Kernel**

Per [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-18-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/), you can manually update to kernel 4.18. If your device is reported to work with this kernel, theoretically it should work out of the box:

Download the kernel here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18/

> Depends on your OS type, download and install the packages in turns:
>
> ```
> linux-headers-4.18.0-xxxxxx_all.deb
> linux-headers-4.18.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
> linux-modules-4.18.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
> linux-image-xxx-4.18.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
> ```
>
> Select generic for common system, and lowlatency for a low latency
>   system (e.g. for recording audio), amd64 for 64bit system, i386 for
>   32bit system, or armhf, arm64, etc for other OS types.

Download required files into a folder, say ~/kernel, then:

```
cd ~/kernel
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Once you have rebooted, verify your kernel with:

```
uname -a
```

**If for some reason you want to get rid of this kernel**

Reboot, go to advanced boot options and select a different kernel and boot. To remove 4.18 run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.18.0-041800-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-041800-generic
```

( you will have to change the package name according to the kernel you installed )

**Confirm Sound Card Works**

Reboot and see that your audio card is recognized using alsamixer:

```
`alsamixer -c1`
```

You may need to change the number next to the flag ***-c*** depending on the sound card you want to choose and edit its settings.

You can adjust levels here. According to answer found by OP, the HP/Speaker output needs to be muted for other outputs to work.

> [image: OP Picture of Alsa]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I already did that the exact same way you stated, and now I did it again and the card doesn't output anything from any of the sources. Do I need do configure the Alsamixer or Pulseaudio somehow?

Comment: OK, but it is 1485 lines the whole info file. Do you want me to post it all of it or a part?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I have edited the question to contain the link to alsa project.

Comment: I am facing another issue at the moment which is related to the kernel installation of 4.18. The problem is when I install 4.18, gdm3 and other packages are getting purged from my system and after a reboot when the OS is trying to boot all I get is the Ubuntu splash screen and nothing more. Should I open another question for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using an ubuntu kernel updater ukuu
http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html

And I upgraded the kernel to 4.18.3 .
My creative sound blaster Z is finally working.
Hope it works for you also.

Comment: Seems like there's still a minor problem with this newer kernel, the sound card stops working after a reboot and I have to plug the audio cord to different ports on the sound card for it to work again after a reboot.